# Why hair leaving the mesh

Tags: animation, particles, hair

With the hairs comb and giving nice shape

[image]

[image]

After applying rotation and scale why the hairs change the shape and length

[image]

I try to animate the brush dropping in the cup. The hair leave the mesh.

[image]

Any suggestion or help whats going wrong. Thanks

Comment: Bake the hair dynamics again.

Comment: @FFeller how to bake plz may i know the steps. Thanks

Comment: Under the Hair Dynamics option there is a tab called "Cache" Open it, and there you will find the "Bake" or "Delete Bake" button.

Comment: @FFeller i bake 50 frame and then animated same result. Hairs leaving the mesh

Comment: Please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @FFeller i have attach the file plz check in the question.

Comment: Unfortunatelly this is a bug (can't use hair dynamics with rigid body), may be they will fix it in the future. You have to bake the rigid body simulation to action, then bake the hair dynamics. https://developer.blender.org/T58044